# How to split a column into three columns in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a data frame as shown below

```
ID  Name     Address
1   Kohli    Country: India; State: Delhi; Sector: SE25
2   Sachin   Country: India; State: Mumbai; Sector: SE39
3   Ponting  Country: Australia; State: Tasmania 
4   Ponting  State: Tasmania; Sector: SE27
```

From the above I would like to prepare below data frame

```
ID  Name     Country   State     Sector
1   Kohli    India     Delhi     SE25
2   Sachin   India     Mumbai    SE39
3   Ponting  Australia Tasmania  None
4   Ponting  None      Tasmania  SE27
```

I tried below code

```
df[['Country', 'State', 'Sector']] = pd.DataFrame(df['ADDRESS'].str.split(';',2).tolist(),
                                   columns = ['Country', 'State', 'Sector'])
```

But from the above again I have to clean the data by slicing the column. I would like to know is there any easy method than this.

Comment: What do you dislike about your solution? Or, what qualities would you look for in an alternative code?

Comment: @DaemonPainter from my code I will have to slice each column to get the expected output. I am not able slice properly.

Comment: Btw, 2 another values are wrong if data are like `Country: Australia; Sector: SE39` or `State: Delhi`, check output carefully.

Comment: @jezrael, please, could you explain what you mean by "2 another values are wrong"? I do not follow you now.

Comment: @JaroslavBezděk - Sure, you are align values by position, not by dictionary like in my answer, so get wrong output column for values in comment above

Comment: Added new row for better understanding to question

Comment: @jezrael, now I get it. Yes, you are right. I am upvoting your solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198232/discussion-between-jezrael-and-jaroslav-bezdk).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use list comprehension with dict comprehension for list of dictionaries and pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
L = [{k:v for y in x.split('; ')  for k, v in dict([y.split(': ')]).items()} 
          for x in df.pop('Address')]

df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(L, index=df.index))
print (df)
   ID     Name    Country     State Sector
0   1    Kohli      India     Delhi   SE25
1   2   Sachin      India    Mumbai   SE39
2   3  Ponting  Australia  Tasmania    NaN
```

Or use `split` with reshape `stack`:

```
df1 = (df.pop('Address')
         .str.split('; ', expand=True)
         .stack()
         .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
         .str.split(': ', expand=True)
         .set_index(0, append=True)[1]
         .unstack()
         )
print (df1)
0    Country Sector     State
0      India   SE25     Delhi
1      India   SE39    Mumbai
2  Australia    NaN  Tasmania

df = df.join(df1)
print (df)
   ID     Name    Country Sector     State
0   1    Kohli      India   SE25     Delhi
1   2   Sachin      India   SE39    Mumbai
2   3  Ponting  Australia    NaN  Tasmania
```

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there

```py
cols = ['ZONE', 'State', 'Sector']
df[cols] = pd.DataFrame(df['ADDRESS'].str.split('; ',2).tolist(),
                                   columns = cols)

for col in cols:
    df[col] = df[col].str.split(': ').apply(lambda x:x[1])
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57588040/how-to-split-a-column-into-three-columns-in-pandas/57588434#comment101638729_57588040

Answer (score 1):

**Original answer**

This can also do the job:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
 [
     {'ID': 1, 'Name': 'Kohli', 'Address': 'Country: India; State: Delhi; Sector: SE25'},
     {'ID': 2, 'Name': 'Sachin','Address': 'Country: India; State: Mumbai; Sector: SE39'},
     {'ID': 3,'Name': 'Ponting','Address': 'Country: Australia; State: Tasmania'}
 ]
)

cols_to_extract = ['ZONE', 'State', 'Sector']
list_of_rows = df['Address'].str.split(';', 2).tolist()
df[cols_to_extract] = pd.DataFrame(
    [[item.split(': ')[1] for item in row] for row in list_of_rows], 
    columns=cols_to_extract)
```

Output would be the following:

```
>> df[['ID', 'Name', 'ZONE', 'State', 'Sector']]

ID  Name    ZONE       State     Sector
1   Kohli   India      Delhi     SE25
2   Sachin  India      Mumbai    SE39
3   Ponting Australia  Tasmania  None
```

**Edited answer**

As @jezrael pointed out very well in [question comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57588040/how-to-split-a-column-into-three-columns-in-pandas#comment101638729_57588040), my original answer was wrong, because it aligned values by position and could tend to wrong key - value pairs, when some of the values were `NaN`s. The following code should work on edited data set.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
 [
     {'ID': 1, 'Name': 'Kohli', 'Address': 'Country: India; State: Delhi; Sector: SE25'},
     {'ID': 2, 'Name': 'Sachin','Address': 'Country: India; State: Mumbai; Sector: SE39'},
     {'ID': 3,'Name': 'Ponting','Address': 'Country: Australia; State: Tasmania'},
     {'ID': 4, 'Name': 'Ponting','Address': 'State: Tasmania; Sector: SE27'}
 ]
)

cols_to_extract = ['Country', 'State', 'Sector']
list_of_rows = df['Address'].str.split(';', 2).tolist()
df[cols_to_extract] = pd.DataFrame(
    [{item.split(': ')[0].strip(): item.split(': ')[1] for item in row} for row in list_of_rows], 
    columns=cols_to_extract)
df = df.rename(columns={'Country': 'ZONE'})
```

Output would be:

```
>> df[['ID', 'Name', 'ZONE', 'State', 'Sector']]

ID  Name    ZONE       State     Sector
1   Kohli   India      Delhi     SE25
2   Sachin  India      Mumbai    SE39
3   Ponting Australia  Tasmania  NaN
3   Ponting NaN        Tasmania  SE27
```